# Keyboard mapping suddenly deconfigured

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Folks, I've came back to work today just to find out that all of sudden my keyboard was deconfigured. maybe that's related to gnome 44 update, I'm not sure.
I'm running 22.04.2 LTS. my keyboard is this one [multilaser TC065 keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opg51.jpg)
As you folks can see, it uses a Brazilian specific format called **ABNT2**

The issue is that not only I'm not able to find a keyboard input source that corresponds to it, but the key mapping is also messed up big time.
If I press "]" button, I get two buttons being pressed at the same time. not only that, my right shift is not working, my left shift has the same issue with "|", etc, the question mark button doesn't work as supposed to.
Since I'm a developer, this crashes my productivity completely.
I've tried running `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` to no avail. It doesn't seem to change anything. not only that, I've also tried to reinstall ubuntu 22.04, the initial settings and layout lookup doesn't work either.

So, I assume that the keymap is broken. Do you folks have any solution or suggestion? Please, I'd hate to go back to windows.

Running `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` yields `[('xkb', 'br'), ('xkb', 'pt')]`

[image: duplicate input for single key press]

Comment: GNOME 44 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson done as requested!

Comment: Ok, then you have two layouts. Try to first switch to the Portuguese one and then back to the Brazilian. Does that help?

Comment: Well, no it doesn't. As of now, I've also tried using xkeycaps to no avail.

Comment: Maybe it's a hardware issue. Do you have an opportunity to test the keyboard on some other computer?

Comment: So, I've done as you suggested and it's not a hardware problem. I've tested it in a windows environment. But, to my surprise, after I've plugged the keyboard back into my Ubuntu system, keymapping was working. I've no idea why, it is really strange as it sounds. The only thing that's currently not working is that ctl+a is not selecting all, but I can manage living with that.

Comment: Great! Would be good if you could submit an answer stating the same thing, so this question can be marked as done.

Comment: Well, after suspending my work yesterday and started working today, I've noticed that the keyboard mapping broke again. It saddens me greatly to note that a windows system has a more reliable solution for such easy problem than Ubuntu.As of now, I can't really tell what configuration changes mapping, if it is xorg, xkb, gnome, etc. That's really annoying, if I knew I'd have to deal with such complexity for such simple stuff, I'd be using Arch instead.